# DataBinding issue with android:progressBackgroundTint

Tags: android, data-binding

I'm trying to use databinding with ProgressBar but I'm getting some error.

I have 2 sets of progressbar, when I use it as below, it works fine,

```
<ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/firstAudioProgressbar"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:progress="50"
                    android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:progressTint="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

But as soon as I start using databinding to decide the **android:progressBackgroundTint** color at runtime, I get a compile time error, see the code and error below,

Code

```
<ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/firstAudioProgressbar"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:progress="50"
                    android:progressBackgroundTint="@{track1.isLongest() ? @color/colorPrimary : @color/colorPrimaryDark}"
                    android:progressTint="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Error

```
Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.ProgressBar android:progressBackgroundTint> that accepts parameter type 'int'

If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.
```

Please let me know, what can I do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set dataBinding in build.gradle?

Comment: I don't think that if I don't set databinding in build.gradle, I'll get the error that I'm getting. Still I cross-checked and whooo it's there. It has been set already.

Answer (score 0):

the [setter](http://%20https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar#setProgressBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) `setProgressBackgroundTintList` takes a `ColorList` object as parameter not an `int`. If you want to use an `int`, you can define a `BindingAdapter`, create the `ColorList` and call the function manually